# Gmail error "Unable to attach file"

Tags: android, kotlin, android-file, file-sharing, android-fileprovider

I am trying to email PDF file using Gmail. However, Gmail app is showing toast:

> Unable to attach file

PDF file is not-corrupt and is generated successfully in application's cache directory.

Code: (**Please comment below if you need code in Java.)**:

```
    val photoURI: Uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.packagename.provider",
            File(this.cacheDir.path + "/Report.pdf"))

    val emailIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO)
    emailIntent.data = Uri.parse("mailto:")
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, photoURI)
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, arrayOf("some@domain.com"))
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject")
    emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
    emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)
    startActivity(emailIntent)
```

Please help

Comment: what is the size of the PDF file?

Comment: less than 1 MB.

Comment: Gmail has read storage permission?

Comment: You also need to give the user permission via a manifest file  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: Yes it has storage permission.

Comment: But I have stored file in Cache and letting client accessing it through `FileProvider`. Why is permission needed?

Comment: @MalwinderSingh Hi! I have the same problem. Could you tell me please how you solved this problem?

Comment: @V.March You can use Gmail APIs for Android.

Answer (score 1):

As per Android Documentation, you need to use the ACTION.SEND intent action in the Intent constructor for attachments.
[Common Intents - Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common)

> ACTION_SENDTO (for no attachment) or
>   ACTION_SEND (for one attachment) or
>   ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE (for multiple attachments)